# Dimension of a vector space with addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: vector-spaces

The dimension of a vector space is determined by the underlying field $\Bbb{F}$, and the addition and scalar multiplication operations (given the set of vectors $V$).

I am aware of how changing the $\Bbb{F}$ can change dimension of $V$, while *not changing* the addition and scalar multiplication. For instance, $\Bbb{R}$ over itself with the usual addition and scalar multiplication has dimension $1$, but over $\Bbb{Q}$ with the same operations, is infinite dimensional. Also, $\Bbb{C}$ over itself with usual operations has dimension $1$, but over $\Bbb{R}$ with same operations has dimension $2$.

I’ve been struggling to find examples where keeping $\Bbb{F}$ fixed, alternate definitions of *addition and scalar multiplication* give a different dimension of $V$.

So help needed.

(I’d appreciate if you give such examples for *both* finite dimensional and infinite dimensional vector spaces.)

---

Apart from bijections between sets of different dimensions over the same field (like making $\Bbb{R}^2$ one-dimensional via a bijection between $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}$), can there be any other examples?

Comment: With "alternate definitions of addition and scalar multiplication" there is no longer a dimension of $V$. Then $V$ is not a $K$-vector space, but an "alternate" vector space.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The “alternate” vector space you talk of will be just *as much* “alternate” as $\Bbb{R}$ over itself to $\Bbb{R}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Get yourself a bijection $f:{\bf R}\to{\bf R}^2$, then define "addition" on $\bf R$ as $f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))$, similarly for scalar multiplication.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you give a more realisable example?

Comment: What part of my example isn't "realisable"?

Comment: Like something *continuous*. I’m informed that this bijection is not continuous.

Comment: There is no continuous bijection between $\bf R$ and ${\bf R}^2$.